# what s the catch with cassandra?

Tags: c#, java, .net, linux, cassandra

ok. I was reading about cassandra and every article i read mentioned that writes in cassandra are very "fast" due to eventual consistency.

I setup cassandra on a linux box, created a schema, and created a client via c# using fluent cassandra client. well , it didnt work cause i wasnt able to access to remote cassandra instance via the fluent cassandra client.

So i installed cassandra on windows, created schema etc.

Next, I inserted 1 million entries to cassandra, which took about 12 minutes. The client and server are on the same machine which is quad core with 8GB ram.

This isnt fast. I did similar test with MongoDB which took 4 minutes to write 1 million documents to it.

I did a smiliar test with ObjectivityOODBMS, it took 30 seconds to insert 1 million objects.

**What s the catch with cassandra, it wasnt fast according to my test?

Would it behave different on a linux server with different client like Java?**

Comment: There's little if any point in testing the performance of a solution designed to be massively distributed on a single box. Try your experiment spread across 10 EC2 instances in a couple of different availability zones (or whatever cloud tech you want), comparing Cassandra with MongoDB with ObjectivityOODBMS. The point of Cassandra is being very fast as a scalable, massively distributed store. (Note: @all: I'm not a Cassandra-head and have no opinion on whether claims of speed -- if indeed such have been made -- are true, so please don't flame me; the point is the test is mis-applied.)

Comment: @user: What's your actual question? "What are the benefits of Cassandra?" "Why is Cassandra so much slower in my test than MongoDB and ObjectivityOODBMS?"

Comment: i understand your reasoning but still i d expect the writes to be much faster than this.

Comment: @user: Why? You're using it in a way completely at odds with what it's designed to do. Remember that Cassandra spreads writes around the nodes in the store, so it really matters whether there's just one node or many when testing.

Comment: @user: "what's the catch" is not a clear, specific question -- and making it bold doesn't make it more specific and clear. ;-)

Comment: even with mysql you can insert million records in less than 10 minutes, why cassandra is slower than all the ones i mentioned. and if i m doing something wrong, and failing to get the proof that cassandra is really fast, what might the be the cause of this?

Comment: @user: I said it above: You're using Cassandra in a way that's completely at odds with what it's designed to do. (And you can insert a million records into a MySQL server on a box like you describe in a *lot* less than 10 minutes. ;-) ) Anyway, I'm going to back out of this conversation because I'm really not a Cassandra expert, it's just the mis-match between the design goals of the tool and your test jumped out at me, is all. Hope you find a good solution for what you're doing. Best,

Comment: ok i got ur point that s why i upvoted it . thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Cassandra beyond doing a bit research on it, but have used MongoDB. Hopefully these thoughts/notes will help.

On a standalone machine, using mongoimport I was able to loaded about 24 million documents into MongoDB in about 6 minutes. Your 4 minutes to write 1 million does seem slow - factors could be: disk speed / how you are inserting - e.g. if you insert 1 doc at a time, then it will be slower. Especially if you use SafeMode (I don't know if Cassandra has the same kind of thing). You should instead insert via one of the batch APIs (e.g. InsertBatch on the C# driver). The same kind of thing would be true for Cassandra (1 by 1 = slow, batched inserts = faster). It's this ability to easily add nodes to scale out writes/reads that really gives you the full (and fair) picture of these technologies.

Obviously on a standalone machine, you will have contention which could be a factor.

The thing to note, is that technologies like MongoDB and Cassandra make it very easy to scale out. e.g. in MongoDB terminology, you can scale your writes (i.e. increase throughput) by using sharding. Especially when you get to larger data volumes, being able to have a dozen nodes all accepting writes at the same time is obviously going to help the IO situation and increase writes. Likewise, you can scale reads with replica sets.

In summary, my question would be how are you inserting those documents - is it done in the most efficient/batched manner?

Comment: i m inserting one at a item time, no batch inserts.

Comment: 1 at a time, written from a single thread, won't be efficient in any db technology. Just like in SQL Server for example, inserting the same 24 million rows takes about 4.5 minutes in a bulk load, but would take a lot longer if done 1 by 1.

Comment: True. i m also using the same approach with others like mongodb and objy.